# Sorting type in datagridview

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

Is there a default sorting in datagridview (in VS 2012)? I just want to know 'coz whenever I add a new data, the data added was placed at the last row. Also where can I change the sorting type 'coz I want my added data to be place at the beginning not to the last.

Comment: Are you adding data directly to the `DataGridView` or do you have a source - like a `DataTable`, `List<object>`, etc. - that you are adding the data to? We need to know *how* you're adding data before we can really help.

Comment: @OhBeWise I have a source table -(employee table). I'm using VS 2012, I created a form to add a new data (employee data) and whenever I add a new employee data, it will show up at the last row of my datagridview. the purpose why I put a datagridview in my project is because I want to see all list of employee.

Comment: If using a `DataTable`, you could do an insert of your data into the beginning of the table, instead of doing an add - which always adds to the end.

Comment: @OhBeWise thanks for the suggestion. :)